# modifying a view tree using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a text box and  a button, i'm trying to figure some messaging functionality using a jQuery tutorial but having trouble finding a good direction. i want the input from the text box to appear in a DIV underneath the DIV containing "Sent messages appear here". testing using [www.htmledit.squarefree.com](http://www.htmledit.squarefree.com) to test the code out below and using F12 (dev mode) i can see the HTML tree

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>

<div>
 <p>
    <input type = "text"
            id  = "textfield" />
    <button type ="button" id="btn">Add Message </button>
 </p>
 <Script>
      $( "#btn" ).click(function() {
           var message = $.trim($("#textfield").val()) 
          $("#sent").append(message);      
          $("#sent").append("<br />");    
                 
      });
 </Script>
</div>

<div id="sent" style="font-style: italic">
     <div>Sent messages appear here.</div>  
</div>
```

The appended message if i type "U" in the textfield output fine on the bottom screen BUT the html tree does not have DIV tags. the following methods seem helpful but the references about them are a bit confusing. .html(), .text(), .append(), and $("html") functions
[image]

the tree should look like this in the element console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you append the text. The message doesn't wrap with 'div tag.
so to do this, It's very easy.

```
$("#sent").append('<div>' + message + '</div>');      
$("#sent").append("<br />");
```

- append function. It's append the element into the target.
  you should add the html tag to append the message
- html function. It's to get the children html element of the target.
- text function. It's to get the all text for the target.
  if you call text function, you only get the string without any html element.
  It's a difference with html.
  Html is get children html element.

Comment: i See. im not sure if this is what it was after. i think using those given function  modify the view tree. but it also does not say i cant do this. is there a way to get the node with ID sent and then create element DIV and get text from the textfield and assign it to the newly created element and append to the parent node? seems a long winded solution but i think that it may be looking for something like that.

Comment: Yes. It's a normal function. $('#sent').apennd('<div class="item">' + message + '</div>');